# Django makes a QueryDict from JSON data

Tags: python, django, rest

I use this code to post some data to a Django-powered site:

```
url = "http://example.com:8080/api/v1/data/"
request = {"info": "", "data": [{"extra": 0, "amount": 100, "id": "10000000016"}, {"extra": 0, "amount": 100, "id": "10000000002"}]}
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [("Authorization", "Token "+self.token), 
                     ("Accept", "application/json"), 
                     ("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")]
opener.open(url, json.dumps(request))
```

Yet, when I read that data in Django, it has parsed it into a `QueryDict`:

```
Raw data received: <QueryDict: {u'{"info": "", ... 0002"}]}': [u'']}>
```

The raw data is taken directly from `request.data` as given to the function that is called from the `urls.py` routing.

When POSTing the same kind of data from an Android app, it works fine. The raw data is a string and can be correctly parsed from JSON.

Comment: `POST`ed raw data should be in `request.body` ([Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body)).

Comment: What's the content type that appears on the django side? Django should only fill the query dict if the input is a one of `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www.form-urlencoded`. `urllib2` automatically sets ``application/x-www.form-urlencoded` and I'm not sure how this interacts with setting `addheaders` on the opener.

Comment: @dhke How can I find out the content type that appears on the django side?

Comment: @BartFriederichs [`request.META['CONTENT_TYPE']`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) is your friend, there.

Comment: @C14L I cannot read `request.body`, as it gives me a "Bad Request" error (HTTP 400).

Comment: Content-Type is indeed application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Does replacing the setup of `addheaders` on the opener by appropriate calls to `add_header()` on the request object make the problem go away?

Comment: @dhke there is no request object, that is just the stuff I want to post as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

As @dhke said in the comments, the problem is that `urllib2` will use `application/x-www.form-urlencoded` by default. A quick search online gave me this code:

```
r = urllib.Request(url, data=json.dumps(request), headers={..})
urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

which works as expected.